# Calculate uncertainty in FFT amplitude

Tags: python, numpy, fft, uncertainty

My [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) programming problem is the following:

I want to create an array of measurement results. Each result can be described as a normal distribution for which the mean value is the measurement result itself and the standard deviation is its uncertainty.

Pseudo code could be:

```
x1 = N(result1, unc1)
x2 = N(result2, unc2)
...

x = array(x1, x2, ..., xN)
```

Than I would like to calculate the [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) of x:

```
f = numpy.fft.fft(x)
```

What I want is that the uncertainty of the measurements contained in x is propagated through the FFT calculation so that f is an array of amplitudes along with their uncertainty like this:

```
f = (a +/- unc(a), b +/- unc(b), ...)
```

Can you suggest me a way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure you can achieve what you want with the data you're given. Certainly you can do a FFT of the means, but a FFT of the deviations doesn't make sense to me. And I'm not sure how you could transform the data to have it make sense.

Comment: If your `x` values are uncorrelated, then the uncertainty of the higher-frequency portions of the fft will be meaningless (infinite uncertainty). In fact, depending on the what the values and uncertainties are in `x`, the uncertainty of fft may be meaningless. The fft depends on the differences between adjacent values.  The way you're currently representing your undertainties, each value is completely independent of the adjacent value. I don't think there's an analytical solution for what you're wanting to do.  You could bootstrap it, but I'm not sure the result is going to have much meaning.

Answer (score 20):

Each Fourier coefficient computed by the discrete Fourier transform
of the array `x` is a linear combination of the elements of `x`; see
the formula for X_k on the [wikipedia page on the discrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform),
which I'll write as

```
X_k = sum_(n=0)^(n=N-1) [ x_n * exp(-i*2*pi*k*n/N) ]
```

(That is, `X` is the discrete Fourier transform of `x`.)
If x_n is normally distributed with mean mu_n and variance sigma_n**2,
then a little bit of algebra shows that the variance of X_k is the sum
of the variances of x_n

```
Var(X_k) = sum_(n=0)^(n=N-1) sigma_n**2
```

In other words, the variance is the same for each Fourier coefficent;
it is the sum of the variances of the measurements in `x`.

Using your notation, where `unc(z)` is the standard deviation of `z`,

```
unc(X_0) = unc(X_1) = ... = unc(X_(N-1)) = sqrt(unc(x1)**2 + unc(x2)**2 + ...)
```

(Note that the distribution of the *magnitude* of X_k is the [Rice distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution).)

Here's a script that demonstrates this result. In this example, the standard
deviation of the `x` values increase linearly from 0.01 to 0.5.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


np.random.seed(12345)

n = 16
# Create 'x', the vector of measured values.
t = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
x = 0.25*t - 0.2*t**2 + 1.25*np.cos(3*np.pi*t) + 0.8*np.cos(7*np.pi*t)
x[:n//3] += 3.0
x[::4] -= 0.25
x[::3] += 0.2

# Compute the Fourier transform of x.
f = fft(x)

num_samples = 5000000

# Suppose the std. dev. of the 'x' measurements increases linearly
# from 0.01 to 0.5:
sigma = np.linspace(0.01, 0.5, n)

# Generate 'num_samples' arrays of the form 'x + noise', where the standard
# deviation of the noise for each coefficient in 'x' is given by 'sigma'.
xn = x + sigma*np.random.randn(num_samples, n)

fn = fft(xn, axis=-1)

print("Sum of input variances: %8.5f" % (sigma**2).sum())
print()
print("Variances of Fourier coefficients:")
np.set_printoptions(precision=5)
print(fn.var(axis=0))

# Plot the Fourier coefficient of the first 800 arrays.
num_plot = min(num_samples, 800)
fnf = fn[:num_plot].ravel()
clr = "#4080FF"
plt.plot(fnf.real, fnf.imag, 'o', color=clr, mec=clr, ms=1, alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(f.real, f.imag, 'kD', ms=4)
plt.grid(True)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.title("Fourier Coefficients")
plt.xlabel("$\Re(X_k)$")
plt.ylabel("$\Im(X_k)$")
plt.show()
```

The printed output is

```
Sum of input variances:  1.40322

Variances of Fourier coefficients:
[ 1.40357  1.40288  1.40331  1.40206  1.40231  1.40302  1.40282  1.40358
  1.40376  1.40358  1.40282  1.40302  1.40231  1.40206  1.40331  1.40288]
```

As expected, the sample variances of the Fourier coefficients are
all (approximately) the same as the sum of the measurement variances.

Here's the plot generated by the script.  The black diamonds are the
Fourier coefficients of a single `x` vector.  The blue dots are the
Fourier coefficients of 800 realizations of `x + noise`.  You can see that
the point clouds around each Fourier coefficent are roughly symmetric
and all the same "size" (except, of course, for the real coeffcients,
which show up in this plot as horizontal lines on the real axis).

[image: Plot of Fourier coefficients]

Comment: Well, my intuition was completely wrong there. That'll teach me to speak up without thinking it through!  Excellent answer!

Comment: It took me a while to show this because of a subtle point I want to make explicit:  the most general form of the variance of `ax` is _not_ `(ax)^2`, but `(ax)(ax)*`, where * denotes complex conjugate.  This isn't an issue when `ax` is real, but it's complex here, and it turns out to be a quite important distinction.